# Can I do this in Web2Py?

Tags: web2py

As a way of evaluating Web2Py I tried to reimplement a web page in Web2Py.
It seemed quite simple to start with but I'm not sure if it works the way I think.

I have a simple page with an input field and button to add an email address.

It has a menu bar which links to other pages

And it has a couple of scrollable DIVs with content derived from a database.

To implement this in Web2Py can I link actions to the various buttons and input fields?
From my quick look at sample code it looks like all request for input is driven from database tables where I have little control over the formatting

I'm sure I'm just looking at it all wrong because I come from a J2EE background and I just need to switch my mind into a different mode.

Any help nudging me in the right direction much appreciated.

Ken

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do it.  The auto-generated forms use postbacks (self submission) but this can be changed and, moreover, you can use custom forms.

I suggest to post the question to the web2py mailing list,  perhaps with a screenshot or sample java code. We will send you back a web2py equivalent.